# DocumentDB Spatial Query - Polygon

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have polygon boundaries stored in a collection.

Can DocumentDB perform spatial queries against polygon data such as: Is my point within a polygon?

e.g. `SELECT * FROM root r WHERE 
   ST_WITHIN({'type':'Point','coordinates':[1, 1]}, r.geometry)`

This is my document:

```
{
  "id": "747941cfb829_1453640096710",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          0,
          0
        ],
        [
          10,
          10
        ],
        [
          10,
          0
        ],
        [
          0,
          0
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although I haven't closely checked your syntax, that should work.

Comment: It's a very common problem, but you are missing an extra pair of square brackets `[` and `]`. The GEOJSON spec requires them to allow for discontinuous polygons and holes. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511736/spatial-indexes-with-documentdb

Comment: @IanShort - Please either edit your question or ask a new question. Don't put new questions (or details such as your polygon document) in comments.